# Jython REST-ful “put” calls with a JSON body that don’t use the “requests” module

Tags: python, json, rest, jython

I am forced to use Jython 2.7 because that is what the vendor provides.
I can’t install the **requests** library on GitHub because of the way the vendor wrapped Jython.
Searches for examples keep returning examples using the **requests** module.
How can I do the following **not** using the **requests** module.

```
import requests

task = {"summary": "Take out trash", "description": "" }
resp = requests.post('https://todolist.example.com/tasks/', json=task)
if resp.status_code != 201:
    raise ApiError('POST /tasks/ {}'.format(resp.status_code))
print('Created task. ID: {}'.format(resp.json()["id"]))
```

Comment: please provide an example request to a public endpoint

Comment: I think requests uses urllib3 under the hood - you may want to check that out

Comment: Please check urllib2: https://www.jython.org/jython-old-sites/docs/library/urllib2.html#request-objects

Comment: Jython 2.7 does not have urllib3, only urllib2.